# TypeError at /admin/ 'set' object is not reversible and argument( ) to reverse must be a sequence

Tags: python, django, web-applications, django-admin, typeerror

My app was working perfectly but when I tried the admin url, this error occurred.I can access every page of the website except for the admin page. 
My project is **mini**
`mini.urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     url(r'^', include('main.urls')),
     url(r'^', include('signup.urls',namespace='signup')),
]
```

`main.urls.py`

```
 from django.conf.urls import url,include
 from . import views

 urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^$', views.index,name='index'),
 ]
```

`signup.urls.py`

```
 from django.conf.urls import url,include
 from . import views

 urlpatterns = {
    url(r'^signup/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_user, name='login'),
    url(r'^userpage/$', views.user_page, name='userpage'),
    url(r'^upload/$', views.upload_file, name='upload'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_user, name='logout'),
    url(r'^(?P<uuid>[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]
                                {12})/$', views.doc_detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<uuid>[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]
                                {12})/decrypt/$', views.doc_decrypt, 
                                            name='docdecrypt'),
     }
```

The error I ran into at /admin/

```
     TypeError at /admin/
     'set' object is not reversible
     Request Method:    GET
     Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
     Django Version:    1.10.5
     Exception Type:    TypeError
     Exception Value:   
     'set' object is not reversible
     Exception Location:    
     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
     packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _populate, line 196
     Python Executable: 
     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
     Python Version:    3.6.0
     Python Path:   
     ['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\django projects\\mini',
     'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-
     32\\python36.zip',
     'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\DLLs',
     'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib',
     'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32',
     'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-
     32\\lib\\site-packages']
```

I tried running my webapp in another pc so I ran into the following error:

```
     TypeError at /admin/
     argument to reversed() must be a sequence
     Request Method:    GET
     Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
     Django Version:    1.10.5
     Exception Type:    TypeError
     Exception Value:   
     argument to reversed() must be a sequence
     Exception Location:    C:\Python27\lib\site-
     packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _populate, line 196
     Python Executable: C:\Python27\python.exe
     Python Version:    2.7.12
     Python Path:   
     ['C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\mini',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\steganography-0.1.1-py2.7.egg',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pillow-4.0.0-py2.7-win32.egg',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\olefile-0.44-py2.7.egg',
     'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
     'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
     'C:\\Python27',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean by object not reversible Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184081/what-does-it-mean-by-object-not-reversible-django)

Answer (score 30):

in signup.urls.py change the brackets from these { } to [ ] these this will work

Comment: When you are using the app routes URL to include into admin main routes URL. Then you have to use [ ] instead of { }

Answer (score 9):

change {} to [] in main.urls.py

Answer (score 4):

Just change `{}` to `[]` in `project.urls.py` :

```
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     url(r'^', include('main.urls')),
     url(r'^', include('signup.urls',namespace='signup'))
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the file urls.py in that file check the Square brackets in the urlpatterns = []
because its in the Curly bracket it will show the 'set' object is not reversible and argument( ) error...Try this it is working...

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with my project, changed the curly brackets {}  to box brackets [] and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

i found solution here, and its work for me

```
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     url(r'^', include('main.urls')),
     url(r'^', include('signup.urls',namespace='signup')),
]
```

remove "," from the last line of urlpatterns array

```
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     url(r'^', include('main.urls')),
     url(r'^', include('signup.urls',namespace='signup'))
]
```

from
http://stackoverflaw.com/question/set-project-is-not-revertable-in-_populate-line-416/

Answer (score 0):

In Main Project urls.py Change urlpatterns tuple from {} to []

PROJECT_NAME/urls.py

Just check and change curly to square at every damn urls.py

and that's it... it'll work!!

Answer (score 0):

step 1: go to signup.urls.py

step 2: change {} to [] in signup urls.py

#################----like that-

urlpatterns = {

```
code
```

}

to

urlpatterns = [

```
code
```

]

Note: it's curly bracket error.