# 127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ won't load up

Tags: python, django

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version: 4.0
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'set' object is not reversible
Exception Location: C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 494, in _populate
Python Executable:  C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject2\\mywebsite',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject2\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject2\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 27 Dec 2021 18:46:36 +0000
```

Comment: add details, like what you are trying to do, what you want to do.

Comment: You may want to consider reviewing : [Another SO question with similar exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43304923/typeerror-at-admin-set-object-is-not-reversible-and-argument-to-reverse-m)

Comment: same error idk what to do !!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us full code that causes that exception.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.