# DJango TypeError - JSFiles object is not reversible

Tags: python, django, object, typeerror, django-widget

I am trying to include [this datepicket widget](https://github.com/pbucher/django-bootstrap-datepicker/) in my DJango version 2.0.2, but it raises error

> **Request Method:**   GET
>   **Request URL:**  http://127.0.0.1:8000/xuser/1/edit
>   **Django Version:**   2.0.2
>   **Exception Type:**   TypeError
>   **Exception Value:** 'JSFiles' object is not reversible
>   **Exception Location:**   D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py in merge, line 114
>   **Python Executable:**    D:\DevTools\Python\python.exe
>   **Python Version:**   3.6.3

I have already looked around for similar errors in following threads

- [What does it mean by object not reversible Django](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43184081/9276329)
- [TypeError at /admin/ 'set' object is not reversible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42952940/9276329)

But these are just **typo errors** about `urlpatterns` and does not even disclose what reversible actually mean in python. The [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20reversible%20object) about reversible object does not yield anything more than the above threads. So, my question is,

- What does reversible object mean?
- How can I solve this issue?

> **Traceback:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/xuser/1/edit

Django Version: 2.0.2
Python Version: 3.6.3
Installed Applications:
['bootstrap3',
 'bootstrap_datepicker',
 'core.apps.CoreConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template D:\Python\dj_abstractbaseuser2\core\templates\core\edit.html, error at line 8
   'JSFiles' object is not reversible
   1 : {# Load the tag library #}
   2 : {% load bootstrap3 %}
   3 : 
   4 : {# Load CSS and JavaScript #}
   5 : {% bootstrap_css %}
   6 : {% bootstrap_javascript %}
   7 : {% block extrahead %}
   8 :  {{ form.media }} 
   9 : {% endblock %}
   10 : 
   11 : {# Display django.contrib.messages as Bootstrap alerts #}
   12 : {% bootstrap_messages %}
   13 : <form method="post">
   14 :     {% csrf_token %}
   15 :     {% bootstrap_field form.first_name %}
   16 :     {% bootstrap_field form.last_name %}
   17 :     {% bootstrap_field form.date_of_birth %}
   18 :     {% buttons %}


Traceback:

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in __getitem__
  157.             field = self.fields[name]

During handling of the above exception ('media'), another exception occurred:

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  835.                     current = current[bit]

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in __getitem__
  163.                     ', '.join(sorted(f for f in self.fields)),

During handling of the above exception ("Key 'media' not found in 'UserEditForm'. Choices are: date_of_birth, first_name, last_name."), another exception occurred:

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  158.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  156.                 response = response.render()

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  58.                 result = self.nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  993.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  676.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  802.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  843.                         current = getattr(current, bit)

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in _media
  148.             base = sup_cls.media

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in _media
  148.             base = sup_cls.media

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in media
  460.             media = media + field.widget.media

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in _media
  148.             base = sup_cls.media

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in _media
  163.                 return m + Media(definition)

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in __add__
  135.         combined._js = self.merge(self._js, other._js)

File "D:\DevTools\Python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in merge
  114.         for path in reversed(list_2):

Exception Type: TypeError at /xuser/1/edit
Exception Value: 'JSFiles' object is not reversible
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by [this issue](https://github.com/pbucher/django-bootstrap-datepicker/issues/12) submitted to the widget's Github page, and has not yet been solved. So I switched to [django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus](https://github.com/monim67/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus), and it is working in my DJango version 2.0.2 just fine. But the question remains that needs to be answered.

> What is a reversible object? Why we get this Error?

The error is raised by the python built-in function `reversed`, that takes a sequence as only parameter and reverses the sequence.

> [**reversed() Parameters**](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/reversed)
> **seq** - sequence that should be reversed.
>
> - Could be an object that supports sequence protocol (`__len__()` and `__getitem__()` methods) as tuple, string, list or range
> - Could be an object that has implemented `__reversed__()`

So all sequences (eg. lists, tuples) are reversible. But to make an object reversible we need to implement a method named `__reversed__`, or both `__len__()` and `__getitem__()` methods. If we pass an object to `reversed()` function which does not fulfill any of the above criteria, it will raise an Exception `TypeError - object is not reversible`.

DJango 2.0 use this `reversed()` function to the assets added by any widget. As the **JSFiles** object used in the above widget does not implement reversible criteria, the error is raised.